# Zero shot react description agent without reference documents

Tags: python, langchain

I'm following an example on LangChain agents with open-source models from [here](https://github.com/AndreasFischer1985/code-snippets/blob/master/py/LangChain_HuggingFace_examples.py).

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of agents.  The following code works. I want to understand, is it possible to launch the agent without reference to the documents that I've defined.  In other words, if I just want to have the agent query the LLM to answer my question, is that possible?  If not, please provide an explanation.

I tried commenting out the func call but get an error like that.

Here is the code

```py
import re
from typing import Optional, List

from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings
from langchain.llms.base import LLM
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

weights=requests.get("https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/WizardLM-13B-V1.2-GGUF/resolve/main/wizardlm-13b-v1.2.Q4_0.gguf")
with open("weights.bin","wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(weights.content)

llamallm = Llama(model_path="./weights.bin",n_ctx=2048)

class CustomLLM(LLM):  
  def _call(self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> str:    
    print("***\n"+prompt+"\n***")
    output = llamallm(prompt, echo=False) #, stop=["Q:", "\n"], max_tokens=100,     
    output = output["choices"][0]["text"]
    output = re.sub("\nAction:(.*)[Dd]atabase(.*)","\nAction: Database",output)    
    output = re.sub("\nAction:(.*)Wikipedia(.*)","\nAction: Wikipedia",output)
    if(output.find("\nAction:")>=0 and output.find("\nObservation:")>output.find("\nAction:")): return(output[0:output.find("\nObservation:")])
    else: return(output)
  @property
  def _llm_type(self) -> str:
    return "custom"

llm=CustomLLM()

hf = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(
  model_name="hkunlp/instructor-large", #"/home/af/Dokumente/Py/Huggingface/hkunlp_instructor-large"
  embed_instruction="Represent the document for retrieval: ",
  query_instruction="Represent the query for retrieval: "
)

embeddings = hf
texts=["The meaning of life is to love","The meaning of vacation is to relax","Roses are red.","Hack the planet!"]

db = Chroma.from_texts(texts, embeddings, collection_name="my-collection") #vs. from_documents
docsearcher = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
  llm=llm,
  chain_type="stuff", #stuff, map_reduce, refine, map_rerank
  return_source_documents=False,
  retriever=db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity",search_kwargs={"k":1}))

tools = [
    Tool(
      name = "Database",
      func=docsearcher.run,
      description="useful for when you need to answer questions of any kind. Input should be a fully formed question."
    )
  ]
agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent="zero-shot-react-description", verbose=True)
agent.run("What is the meaning of life?")
```